# pandas groupby resample unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'grp': [1, 2] * 2, 'value': range(4)},
                  index=pd.Index(pd.date_range('2016-03-01', periods=7)[::2], name='Date')
                 ).sort_values('grp')
```

I wanted to group by `'grp'` and resample my index daily, forward filling missing values.  I expected this to work:

```
print df.groupby('grp').resample('D').ffill()

            grp  value
Date                  
2016-03-01    1      0
2016-03-05    1      2
2016-03-03    2      1
2016-03-07    2      3
```

It did not.  So I tried this:

```
print df.groupby('grp', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.resample('D').ffill())

            grp  value
Date                  
2016-03-01    1      0
2016-03-02    1      0
2016-03-03    1      0
2016-03-04    1      0
2016-03-05    1      2
2016-03-03    2      1
2016-03-04    2      1
2016-03-05    2      1
2016-03-06    2      1
2016-03-07    2      3
```

It did work.  Shouldn't these two methods have produced the same output?  What am I missing?

---

Response to ayhan's comment

```
print sys.version
print pd.__version__

2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
0.18.0
```

ayhan showed that the results looked the same on python 3, pandas 18.1

After updating pandas to 18.1

```
2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
0.18.1
```

The issue has been resolved.

Comment: Python 3, Pandas 0.18.1 returned this: http://i.imgur.com/qL9rb3E.png

Comment: Must be a 2.7 issue?  Thx ayhan.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but I had the same issue with Python 3, Pandas 0.18.0 so I guess it is about Pandas version.

Comment: I'll update now and see.  That did it.  Ayhan, post this as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [one of the issues](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12923) due to the changes in [resample API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#resample-api) in version 0.18.0.

It works as expected in 0.18.1:

```
df.groupby('grp').resample('D').ffill()
Out[2]: 
                grp  value
grp Date                  
1   2016-03-01    1      0
    2016-03-02    1      0
    2016-03-03    1      0
    2016-03-04    1      0
    2016-03-05    1      2
2   2016-03-03    2      1
    2016-03-04    2      1
    2016-03-05    2      1
    2016-03-06    2      1
    2016-03-07    2      3
```